# I am using gdb to call a simple c++ function but it fails

Tags: c++, gdb

The program is very simple:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(){  cout<<"hello from function"<<endl;  }

int main(){
cout<<"hello from main"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

And I compiled this program as follows:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main
```

Open the gdb, set a break point and run.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:9
9       cout<<"hello from main";
```

Then call the function:

```
(gdb) call test()
(gdb)
```

Nothing happens.....why???

Comment: It works for me, for example - try adding more information about your OS, GCC and GDB versions, how you start GDB and the program etc.

Comment: version:GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-37.el5_7.1)
I start it as follows:

$gdb main
(gdb)run

Answer (score 1):

Your GDB output at breakpoint does not match your source (missing `endl`).

I am guessing that you *also* forgot to add `endl` inside `test()` when you ran it under GDB, in which case the behavior you got under GDB is *expected* due to buffering.

Try rebuilding your program *exactly* as it is currently stated and rerunning it under GDB again. Chances are, it will now work.